# From server Class into an array Swift

Tags: swift, parsing, collections, view

I want to display my data I parse from server into my view collection, so I used PFQuery as the following

```
func LoadData(){
    let query = PFQuery(className: "AntStore")
    query.findObjectsInBackground {(returned, error) -> Void in
        if error !=  nil {
            print(error!)
        } else {
            if let data = returned {
                for object in data {
                    self.TitlesArray.append(object.object(forKey: "Title") as! String)
                    print(self.TitlesArray)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't put it in a single array to send it to the view collection variable!! Any help ?

Comment: this is what I got as result !

["Locker"]
["Locker", "Curious"]
["Locker", "Curious", "Ideas"]
["Locker", "Curious", "Ideas", "Books"]
["Locker", "Curious", "Ideas", "Books", "Links"]
["Locker", "Curious", "Ideas", "Books", "Links", "Rate"]
["Locker", "Curious", "Ideas", "Books", "Links", "Rate", "Imager"]
["Locker", "Curious", "Ideas", "Books", "Links", "Rate", "Imager", "Comi"]
["Locker", "Curious", "Ideas", "Books", "Links", "Rate", "Imager", "Comi", "Trash"]

Comment: The previous comment will be more useful if it is added to the question

Answer (score 0):

You are printing inside the loop, move the print statement outside the loop as follows:

```
func LoadData(){
    let query = PFQuery(className: "AntStore")
    query.findObjectsInBackground {(returned, error) -> Void in
        if error !=  nil {
            print(error!)
        } else {
            if let data = returned {
                for object in data {
                    self.TitlesArray.append(object.object(forKey: "Title") as! String)
                }
                print(self.TitlesArray) //Moved print outside the loop
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but its not working !! it prints empty arrays

Comment: @BilelTlili I have updated answer can you try that and see if that works